# Export from Access to Excel, add worksheet to existing Workbook

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I would like to automate a process of exporting data from Access query to Excel workbook.  Each query relates to a batch.  Each worksheet in a workbook relates to a batch.  For example: Excel workbook called Jun2019.xlsx, might have batch1 relating to the worksheet named batch1.  Then save each workbook into a different file path.

I am looking for some guidance, whether it can be done via Access VBA or would need a separate step to export xlsx from access and run procedure in Excel?

Comment: You can do this from either Access or Excel, just a matter of your own preference.  Either way, put the query's results in a Recordset object, and then output the Recordset into an Excel worksheet.  If you run into a specific problem, edit your question to include code you've tried.

Comment: For ideas review http://www.accessmvp.com/KDSnell/EXCEL_Export.htm#ExpCopyFromRst

Answer (score 0):

Working from Access VBA your code should look something like this.

Please note where some actions are done by `Apxl` object, while others must be done by the object's `Application` property. I have found this issue vital in various Excel actions done from MS Access.

First create an Excel objet:

```
dim Apxl as Object, xlWorkbook as Object ,xlWorksheet as Object
Set Apxl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
```

Next If the `Workbook` (the file) exists already,  open it:

```
ApXl.Workbooks.Open("C\:MyPath\MyFileName.xlsx")
```

Or create a new one:

```
Set xlWorkbook = Apxl.Application.WorkBooks.Add 
xlWorkbook.SaveAs "C\:MyPath\MyFileName.xlsx"
```

Now you can approach the `Worksheat` Object by it's name, or ordinal number (startin by 1 ):

```
Set xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Worksheets("MySheetName")
Set xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
```

If sheet does not exist, you can create a new one:

```
xlWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
```

The new worksheet will be added to the **beginning** of the collection.

You can also rename the `WorkSheet`:

```
Set xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
xlWorksheet.Name = "MyNewName"
```